# D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bytewidth "not working"

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm having some issues with Direct3D. Namely the vertex buffer and its ByteWidth member.

I want to draw two quads, so I create my vertex buffer like so:

```
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT3 normal;
    XMFLOAT2 texCoord;
};

    ....

void GameWindow::CreateVerticesAndBuffer()
{
    Vertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },

        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT; //Will not ever change after creation (??)
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;
    desc.StructureByteStride = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(data));
    data.pSysMem = vertices;

    HR(device->CreateBuffer(
        &desc,
        &data,
        &vertexBuffer));

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
}
```

This code produces some weird results as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/1HUMbwH.png). The back face is mirrored for some reason.

But, if I change

`desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8`

to

`desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 9`

It is [drawn correctly](http://i.imgur.com/j34ZI3Y.png).

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

EDIT: Here is my CreateInputLayout:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDesc[] = {
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0  },
    { "TEX", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0  }
};

hRes = device->CreateInputLayout(
    inputDesc,
    ARRAYSIZE(inputDesc),
    vertexShaderSource->GetBufferPointer(),
    vertexShaderSource->GetBufferSize(),
    &vertexInputLayout);
```

Comment: @ItzWarty Why are you assuming this is C++/CLI? There's nothing in there that's not pure C++.

Comment: @ItzWarty: StructureByteStride is for passing structured data to shaders, not for vertex buffers.

Comment: @Semicolon: Can you post your CreateInputLayout call?

Comment: @Trillian I posted my CreateInputLayout call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` (float3) for your TEX member.  Change it to `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT` and it should work.